# Display a list of names if today's date equals a date in any adjacent cell on the same row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

My spreadsheet has "variant" names in Column B, and relevant dates in adjacent columns C-H on the same row. I have included a screenshot below

I want to create formula that will display a list "variant" names when "todays's date" (`today()`) matches a date in the adjacent Columns C-H on the same row as the "variant" name. The list would be displayed in Column I.

For example:

- If today's date is, say, 26 March 2021 then (based on the data in the screenshot below) the list of "variants" would be those five names circled in red.
- When today's date is 27 March 2021, the list of variants would automatically update to include only those five names with a value of 2021-03-27 (in the same row as the name) in one of the adjacent Columns C-H.

Normally some kind of `vlookup/hlookup/lookup` might do the trick, but this has to evaluate 6 date values and return the "variant" name from a column to the left of the date columns. Maybe a `query` or `filter` might be better since they could also apply to any new rows of data.

[image: my Google Sheet]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of you search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén Could I ask you to reopen this question that has been corrected by @Tedinoz? Thank you (Rubén and Tedinoz) very much for your help.

Comment: Done c.c @Tedinoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your list can be generated in several ways (and probably more efficiently than the following answer). Please consider this as one alternative. I hope that I have not misunderstood your requirements; if so, then please let me know.

---

Insert this formula in Cell I3 (based on the sample data shown below):

`=query({B3:H7},"select Col1 where Col2 = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' OR Col3 = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' OR Col4 = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' OR Col5 = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' OR Col6 = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' OR Col7 = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")`

Note: cell B1 contains this formula:

`=today()`

---

**Sample**

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz. I tried exactly as you wrote but still got a formula error. Maybe the local language settings have something to do with this because I have Polish in the system (I'm guessing). Can you try the formula in my duplicate sheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11a--_xkFyQHdJK3j_EhDYh2FgCDyVDqzaBdT3ZcdyZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was right. I changed the locale to US and it worked :) Thank you @Tedinoz :)

Comment: This recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66948103/1330560) addresses the issue of comma vs semi-colon argument separators. Btw, if the answer was useful, then you might consider [accepting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it