# Copy Google Sheet's cell if there is today's date in any cell next to

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I need a formula that would copy all the cells from column B if there is today's date in any cell next to (same row). The copied cells would go to empty column I, each cell under the next.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Would you please describe your own efforts to solve your problem.

Comment: Your question says that you want to "copy" the cell. A formula is always dynamic and depends on the values of its arguments. For example, if today's date is 26/3/2021, a formula could make the value in cell B13 appear in cell I13; but tomorrow (when the date is 27 March 2021), the contents of cell I13 would be blank. Is this consistent with your idea of a "copy" of the value in Column B?

Comment: This is almost what I mean. I would like the copied cells from column B to end up in column I with no free cells between them.
In column B the values are constants and in columns C-H there are date variables calculated on the basis of the date in the first cell C2. (D2=C2+1, E2=D2+2 etc.)

Comment: Posting again a question without improving it significantly might cause that it be closed  as duplicate of the previous post. If the previous post is delete, it might be undeleted.

Comment: @Rubén I wasn't aware of any duplication, but I was in the act of posting an answer to this question when I found that it was closed. Would you please re-open and I will post an answer.

Comment: @Tedinoz I'm sorry to hear that you worked on a response. I think that the original question should not be reopened yet.

Comment: I give up. Before someone answers my question, the moderator closes the topic for no specific reason.

Comment: @odyn1982 Your questions were closed because more detail/clarity is required and you have supplied a lot of that extra information in these comments. _BUT_ there is one thing to clarify/confirm... if today's date was/is 26 March 2021, then the list in Column I would contain only the five names from Column B that are circled in red. So, if today's date is 27 March 2021 - would you please confirm that the list in Column I would contain only the five names from Column B with a date of 27 March 2021. If not, please advise what names should be on the list on 27/3/2021.

Comment: @Tedinoz Yes, that's 100% correct. If today's date is 27 March 2021 then "Column I" would contain only five names from Column B.

Comment: @odyn1982 okay have a look at [Display a list of names if today's date equals a date in any adjacent cell on the same row [closed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/152029/196152), and see whether this is an accurate/reliable explanation of what you are trying to do; also edit the question if there is an error or any further information that you would like to include. Once you are happy with that question, I suggest that you send a respectful comment to Ruben (a comment under that question) to ask if the question could be reopened.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you very much for your help :)